# Can I set a value to the golbal variable in $(document).ready(function(){}); and use the same variable outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global-variables, document-ready

Suppose, I have one global variable `'x'` and I want to set it to value `'2'` i.e. `x=2` inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` function.

Now I want to use the variable `'x'` having value `'2'` outside `$(document).ready(function(){})` function.

Note that the usage of variable `'x'` after `$(document).ready(function(){})` should be independent i.e. it should not be used inside some function or callback function.

Is it possible to do so? If yes how? If no why?

Please provide me detailed solution with proper reasons for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Note that the usage of variable 'x' after $(document).ready(function(){}) should be independent i.e. it should not be used inside some function or callback function.

If it isn't inside another function, then you will be trying to use it **immediately** … which is before the `ready` event fires … so it will be before the value has been assigned to the variable.

In short: No.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to declare a global variable x before the function.

Like:
var x;
$(document).ready(function(){ x = 2; }); console.log(x);

In this case you are defining a global variable and assigning a value to that variable under a function. So you can access that x outside that function as well.